# Two conditions for continuity?

Tags: general-topology

Below, $f$ is a function $X\rightarrow X'$ between topological spaces. Are both those conditions equivalent with continuity?

- $x\in (f^{-1}(A'))^i\Rightarrow f(x)\in (A^{\prime})^i$, for any $A'\subseteq X'$, where $B^i$ stands for the interior of B.
- If $x$ is a cluster point of $(x_k)_\mathbb N$, then $f(x)$ is a cluster point of $(f(x_k))_\mathbb N$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Consider what happens when $X$ is $\Bbb R$ with the [cocountable topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology), $X'$ is $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology, and $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Obviously your function is discontinuous, but I can't figure out what the interior of an arbitrary subset of X is...

Comment: @Lehs: Let $A\subseteq X$. If $X\setminus A$ is countable, then $A$ is open and is equal to its interior. If $X\setminus A$ is not countable, can $A$ contain a non-empty open set?

Comment: OK! I see. An illusion less to carry on. So the answer to the first of my statements is negative. I was more insecure of the second. Well, that is for sure, I've to quit with mathematics or restart with it. Neither my knowledge nor my intuition is up to date. Thanks!

Comment: @Lehs: You’re welcome! It was actually an interesting question, even if it did result from a faulty intuition.